# CComboBox FindString empty

Tags: string, visual-c++, combobox, mfc, is-empty

The MFC CComboBox allows a person to do an `AddString` of an empty string. I just proved that by doing a GetCount() before and another after the `AddString`; Count was 0, then it became 1; and the GUI also seems to reflect it, as its list was an huge empty box, and when adding it became a one-liner.

I also proved it further by doing

```
            int a = m_combo.GetCount();
            CString sx= _T("Not empty string");
            if(a == 1)
                m_combo.GetLBText(0, sx);

            TRACE(_T("Start<%s>End"), sx);
```

and the Output window displays

```
File.cpp(9) : atlTraceGeneral - Start<>End
```

so we conclude the `sx` variable is empty.

Then I do a `FindString` having a CString m_name variable which is empty:

```
 int idx= m_combo.FindString(-1, m_name);
```

And it returns `CB_ERR`!

Is it standard behavior for empty string entries? Official documentation doesn't say anything about it!

If it is, what is the simplest way to override it? Is there some parameter or change in the resources to change the behaviour? If there is not, I am thinking about deriving or composing a class just for the case where the string is Empty!

Comment: A combo box is a user-visible control. What is the use-case for throwing an empty (invisible) string at the user? Pre-emptive downvote for not being a practical programming question.

Comment: See if `FindStringExact` does what you want. `FindString` searches for an item that *starts with* the given string - which doesn't really make sense when the given string is empty.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: I tested with `FindStringExact ` and it has the same behavior; it also returns `CB_ERR`. Anyway , Update to your comment because you were paying more attention to the documentation than me. It works really the way you described: `FindString` matches entries that start with the prefix inputted as the string parameter to the function call; `FindStringExact` matches entries that are equal to the inputted parameter.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: I bet lots of code in the whole world must be wrongly using `FindString` in places it should really be using `FindStringExact`! These functions have a nomenclature problem, as a person would expect `FindString` to be a case-insensitive full match, and `FindStringExact` to be a case-sensitive full-match!

Comment: @IInspectable: Believe it or not, this is a practical programming question. I have a costumer complaining about seeing a message "The parameter is incorrect" due to this. Immediately after this code, I do a `SetCurSel` and in another part later I do a `GetLBText(m_combo.GetCurSel(), str);` . In this method's line `GetLBText(nIndex, rString.GetBufferSetLength(GetLBTextLen(nIndex)));` the `GetBufferSetLength` will receive a -1 length and it will fail, as everybody can expect!

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Errata: Where I said "Update to your comment because ..." I really meant "I Upvote your comment because ..."

Comment: What about using `SetItemData` and `GetItemData` to solve this? Instead of relying on finding match null string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it manually for the empty string and it works!

```
CString sItem;
int idx_aux= CB_ERR;

// need it because FindString, FindStringExact and SelectSring return CB_ERR when we provide an empty string to them!

if(m_name.IsEmpty())
{
    for (int i=0; i<m_combo.GetCount(); i++)
    {
        m_combo.GetLBText(i, sItem);

        if(sItem.IsEmpty())
        {
            idx_aux= i;
            break;
        }
    }
}
else
    idx_aux= m_combo.FindString(-1, m_name);
```